# is there a way to download my bitcoins to a pc wallet?

Tags: wallet

i have .000313 in bitcoin in paxful wallet to start off. 
id like to download it to my bitcoin wallet on my pc.

I just need some help.

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely a good idea, it's always safer to store your bitcoin where you control the private keys instead of a custodial wallet like the one on Paxful. The first step would be to follow the instructions at bitcoin.org on [setting up a full node](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node).

If you don't have the storage space to run a full node on your PC, make sure and read the section on [reducing storage requirements](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#reduce-storage) that will allow you to run a full node without the massive storage requirements.

Once you have your node setup, you should [follow this Paxful faq](https://kb.paxful.com/knowledgebase/how-to-send-bitcoins/) on sending bitcoin to an external wallet.

There is a caveat though: the fees are going to make transferring .000313 BTC on chain pretty much pointless. If you check out [estimatefee.com](https://estimatefee.com) currently, the average fee costs about 309 satoshi per byte which works out to an average of 0.00115566 BTC, which is more than your balance. You might want to wait to send your BTC from Paxful when you have a larger balance, or the fees go down.

Comment: IMHO [Electrum](https://electrum.org) is a better desktop option for new users.  Bitcoin Core (150GB and many days of syncing) is not a good way to start off with Bitcoin.